# How to update/recalculate the inverse of matrix after changed one element's value?

Tags: matrices, inverse, sparse-matrices

I have a large sparse matrix `A` and have gotten its inverse matrix `inv(A)` . Then I need to change an element value to get a new matrix, `A1`. I am trying to get the inverse of `A1`. Is there any way to do it , rather than recalculate the `inv(A1)`? Could I get some benefits from `A` or `inv(A)`? Is there some method for updating?

This may be a basic math problem. But it confused me a lot. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: If you kept track of what steps you took and the arithmetic involved in calculating the first inverse... then sure, you can reuse some of that same work for the second and possibly save a little bit of time... Going *straight from the result* of the first to the second though in a manner like you are hoping for will likely be impossible however.

Comment: Is the Sherman Morrison formula what you need?https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula

Comment: @user619894 Yes, I need this formula. But now someone told me  it is less precise. So I am testing my data.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you. I am trying with the arithmetic.